# Extracting subdirectory from a git repo into another repo and keeping dir structure?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

There are several subtrees in my repo (e.g. `./sub1/`, `./sub2/`, ..) which I would like to extract into separate repos, keeping commit history and the same dir structure, i.e. a new repo for `sub1` should have `./sub1/` subtree from the main repo. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use git's filter-branch with subtree filter.

Here are the steps:

1. Clone a working copy. This operation will alter local repo, so we must have a working copy first. You can either do a git clone as below or just copy it.

   ```
   git clone --no-hardlinks <original repository> <working copy>
   ```
2. Use subtree fileter.

   ```
   cd <working copy>

   git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <subdir path to be splited> --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

   # reset current working directory
   git reset --hard
   ```
3. We have accomplished our task, it is better to do some cleaning work, because lots of old objects became unreachable.

   1. Delete old remote

      ```
      git remote rm origin
      ```
   2. Remove old reflog

      ```
      # clean unneeded reflog in order to free space
      refbak=$(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/)
      if [ -n "$refbak" ];then
          echo -n $refbak | xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
      fi
      git reflog expire --expire=now --all
      ```
   3. Repack and compress the repo

      ```
      # prune loose objects
      git gc --aggressive --prune=now
      ```

This will make the repos structure change from

```
repo/
    |-- sub1/
        |-- sub11
        |-- sub12
    |-- sub2
```

to

```
repo/
    |-- sub11
    |-- sub12
```

But, it seems you want it to became

```
repo/
    |-- sub1/
        |-- sub11
        |-- sub12
```

Then, there is one more step need to be done, rewrite the git commit history with index-filter.

```
# replace <subdir path> with the actual subdir path, for this case, it should be "sub1"
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t-&<subdir path>/-" | GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && mv $GIT_INDEX_FILE.new $GIT_INDEX_FILE' HEAD
```