# Intense Restructure of large Git repo into multiple new repos

Tags: git, git-subtree, git-filter-branch

I've found several simple examples using both filter-branch and subtree, but they always are just moving 1 directory around.  I'd like to take the following repo:

```
/
  Project1.sln
  Project2.sln
  Source/
    CommonLib.Data/
    CommonLib.Web/
    Project1.Data/
    Project1.Web/
    Project1.Other/
    Project2.Data/
    Project2.Web/
```

And move things out to their own repos, with the following structure:

```
# CommonRepo
/
  CommonLib.Data/
  CommonLib.Web/

# Project1Repo
/
  Project1.sln
  Project1.Data/
  Project1.Web/
  Project1.Other/

# Project2Repo
/
  Project2.sln
  Project2.Data/
  Project2.Web/
```

While maintaining the entire history.  To complicate things, there are 1 or more branches of the original repo that correspond to each project, and thus the version of CommonLib the other projects referred to may be slightly different.

I'd like to use git subtree add to add a reference back to the CommonLib in each of the new repos at the correct tag/revision, but first I need a way to split several directories at once off into their own location.

git subtree split -P seems to only want 1 directory, and I haven't been able to get filter-branch to grab the multiples, either.  I'm on a windows box so don't have all the scripting niceties set up to make this easier.

Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, I recommend you keep the common lib included in your projects especially due to the divergence you spoke about, so your ideal structure should be:

```
# CommonRepo
/
  CommonLib.Data/
  CommonLib.Web/

# Project1Repo
/
  Project1.sln
  Project1.Data/
  Project1.Web/
  Project1.Other/
  CommonLib/         # I recommend that you do whatever restructuring needed to support this in a sub-directory
    CommonLib.Data/
    CommonLib.Web/

# Project2Repo
/
  Project2.sln
  Project2.Data/
  Project2.Web/
  CommonLib/         # I recommend that you do whatever restructuring needed to support this in a sub-directory
    CommonLib.Data/
    CommonLib.Web/
```

### Now to handle the splitting:

when you split, as long as you don't use different annotations or something the commit ids will be compatible and should play nicely with merge. So you can start by extracting the CommonLib by itself.

1. I recommend you clone your whole depo before starting just to be sure you don't lose anything.

   ```
   git clone <big-repo> <big-repo-clone>
   ```
2. Prepare the old repo

   ```
   pushd <big-repo-clone>
   # split for the common lib
   git checkout master  # assuming you want your common lib at master
   git subtree split --prefix=Source --branch=temp-commonLib

   # split the projects from their respective branches
   git checkout <branch-for-project1>
   git subtree split --prefix=Source --branch=temp-project1

   # split the projects from their respective branches
   git checkout <branch-for-project2>
   git subtree split --prefix=Source --branch=temp-project2
   ```
3. Now we need to clean out the parts of those projects that we don't want there. Since they're mixed in you can't really use sub-tree but you can filter-branch to rewrite the history without the other parts.

   ```
   # strip unrelated parts from the CommonLib
   git checkout temp-commonLib
   git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch Project1* Project2*' HEAD

   # strip unrelated parts from the Project1
   git checkout temp-project1
   git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch CommonLib* Project2*' HEAD

   # strip unrelated parts from the Project2
   git checkout temp-project2
   git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch CommonLib* Project1*' HEAD
   ```

   The prune empty will strip the commits that become empty because they only contained changes that were in the folders you removed.

   **Note:** All of these changes are at the /source level so that it can be the new root for each project. You can later add your solution back in. Or you can use this prune technique with clones instead of subtrees, and when you're all done you can just move all the contents from '/Source' to '/'

   Now your  is going to have extra branches and backups in `refs/original/refs/heads/<branch-name>`. If during the process you get a fatal error with filter-branch, you can re-create the branch and start again, or if you're confident it didn't do anything yet you can delete this backup with: `git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/<branch-name>`.
4. Now just create new repos to store the projects created from those branches

   ```
   popd # to get out of <big-repo-clone>

   mkdir <new-repo>
   pushd <new-repo>

   git init
   git pull <big-repo-clone> <name-of-branch> # like temp-project1
   popd # to get out of the <new-repo>
   ```
5. One last thing, lets pull the CommonRepo into the projects.

   ```
   pushd <new-project-repo>
   git subtree add --prefix=CommonLib <new-commonlib-repo>
   ```

You then just need to bring in the .sln files (I'll leave this last step up to you).

Comment: I don't think you need to specify multiple directories at a time to accomplish your goal

Comment: In your example and edit of my post I think you've reorganized my hierarchy.  The web and non-web portions of each project are peers, the web directory does not exist under the other directory that needs to move.

Comment: oh apologies. I couldn't really understand your directory structure as it was written. Is this what you mean (see edit in my post)

Comment: No, there is no common path for the two directories associated with a given project.  I'll edit yours to reflect it more accurately, and show the additional complexity as I've simplified things.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the updated initial structure, and I tested it.

Comment: I'll give this a shot today.  Last time I did a filter-branch command it took over 24 hours, and at the end I couldn't even tell that it had done anything, but I'll go ahead and start it up and see how it goes.

Comment: If you have a huge history with the projects intermingled that's quite a hefty job one way or another. You could save yourself time by re-writing history later. So, if you just make branches for the common lib, project1 and project2, and just commit deletes for the stuff you don't need, then you can start new repos from each of those branches. Then you can use grafting or filter-branch later to strip out the other projects.

Comment: Excellent answer. If the original repo is changed afterwards (eg. maintenance), can you pick up/merge those changes to the new structure without major pain? I mean, filter-branch probably "burns the bridge" doesn't it?

Comment: I think if you graft or filter branch the hashes would no longer match up, but you could probably still apply a diff patch from one branch to the other.

Answer (score 1):

My program git_filter can do the split for you. I wrote it because all the other solutions were very slow on our large repository. It is here:

https://github.com/slobobaby/git_filter

It creates multiple branches for each extract of the original repository. At the moment I have a test branch here:

https://github.com/slobobaby/git_filter/tree/subdir

which will create a new branch containing a subdirectory of the original repository renamed to the root of the new.

It takes a few minutes to run compared to hours or days for the git-core based solutions.

There is a script included which then pushes these new branches to new clean repositories.

Comment: Oops I didn't see you were on windows. You could always start a virtual machine with linux in it... or port my code to windows.

Comment: I found your project while searching yesterday, but I wasn't sure how to configure it to do what I want.  If there are multiple branches on the original repo, will those branches be carried over into the new repos by the tool?

Comment: No. Each branch is pushed as a new separate repository as a second stage of the process. It really helps the process speed to reuse the original objects instead of creating new ones. The push_clean_repos script creates the clean repositories.

Comment: If I had read my own code I could have seen the subdir branh does the opposite of what you want and moves the root directory down to a subdirectory. This new branch at https://github.com/slobobaby/git_filter/tree/flatten does what you want. I even added the configuration which rewrites the example repository you describe above. Just checkout and make and run ./git_filter test.cfg with your repo in test under the current directory :)

Comment: In answer to the question about multiple branches the answer is per default it only takes one branch and filters it. You need to run it several times to filter several branches. I could probably change it to execute on all commits instead of just a certain branch's.

Comment: Things are really a mess atm.  There is at least one branch for each project, each with a copy of some part of the entire repo, as things get merged between branches, primarily to share new additions to the Common code.  There are over a dozen pairs of directories, and dozens of branches in the history, with (for the most part) 1 active branch per project.

Answer (score 1):

For me, instead of trying to figure out how to split out many parts of a repo, I prefer to clone the original, then pare it down by slicing away what I don't want. Then in the original (or another clone) I pare away the parts I've split out. I've found it to be a much easier, iterative approach, with much greater visibility over what's happening.

See my recent answer on this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22210682/955926