# How do i create a branch from an existing folder in an existing branch in a git repository?

Tags: git, branch

How do i create a branch from an existing folder present in another branch in a git repository? For ex:

Existing Repository name: A_repo

Branch Name: 1- Branch

Folders: 
Develop,
Maintenance,
Production,
Non-Production

Now i need to create Develop branch from Develop folder(present in A_Repo) under new repository B_Repo.

Thanks & Regards,

Swagath

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting subdirectory from a git repo into another repo and keeping dir structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801763/extracting-subdirectory-from-a-git-repo-into-another-repo-and-keeping-dir-struct)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you maybe have a legacy repo with folders per environment (likely from TFS or something like that?) and are trying to migrate to a more git-friendly structure with branches per environment instead?

If so, and if you plan to use git, it's probably a good idea.  But be aware that sharing changes between the two going forward wouldn't be straightforward - so this works best if you're able to migrate *everything* to the new structure and then dispose of the old repo.

You can do this using the `subdirectory-filter` option of `git filter-branch` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).  (On current versions of git, you will get a warning that they recommend switching to a different tool called `git filter-repo`; I haven't yet learned about this new tool, and this is a simple enough operation using `filter-branch`, but you might choose to look up the `filter-repo` docs instead.)

For example you could create a new `B-repo` containing the history of `1-Branch` by

```
$ git clone --single-branch -b 1-branch A-repo ./B-repo
$ cd B-repo
$ git remote remove origin
```

and then create the `develop` branch by

```
$ git checkout -b develop
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter develop --prune-empty -- develop
```

If need be, you could repeat this procedure to create branches for each environment.  You would have to do a little clean-up in between `filter-branch` runs to remove backup refs it creates, as it won't do a new run if there's a previous backup.

```
$ git update-ref -d refs/original/refs/heads/develop
$ git checkout 1-branch
$ git checkout -b production
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter production --prune-empty -- production
```

and so on.

Once you've created whatever new branches you need, you would remove `1-Branch` from your new repo.

```
$ git branch -D 1-branch
```

If you find that excessive space is being taken up by the now-defunct `1-Branch` data (which is still in the repo database) you could clean it up in a couple ways.  Just pushing the new branches to a remote will probably suffice, but I don't see anything in the docs to guarantee that.  Similarly, you can just re-clone the new repo and *probably* only the new branches' data will be copied, but again I'm not sure that's guaranteed behavior.

To explicitly force a cleanup you could delete the `1-Branch` reflog (and any last `original/*` refs) and then run `git gc`.  Since this clone was created just now for creating the new branches, it doesn't have any valuable reflogs, so you can safely delete them all.

```
$ rm -rf .git/refs/original
$ rm -rf .git/logs
$ git gc --prune=now --force --aggressive
```